# Why is my WCF wshttpbinding client doesn't work at another computer?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wcf

First, i host my wcf service in winform and i try to use wsHttpBinding. My client application work only in my development computer. Why is my WCF wshttpbinding client doesn't work at another computer? in another computer it showed "the caller was not authenticated by the service" when i execute the service

Here is my WCF winform host configuration (app.config) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="DBCS"
           connectionString="data source=localhost;DataBase=LatihanSP;Integrated Security=SSPI"
           providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="XServerSvcBehavior">
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="XServerSvcBehavior" name="ServerTier.ServiceClient">
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
                    name="XServerSvcBasicHttpEndPoint" contract="ServerTier.IServiceClient" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
                    name="XServerSvcMexHttpEndPoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:7777/SampleSvc" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And here is my client app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="XServerSvcBasicHttpEndPoint" />
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:7777/SampleSvc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="XServerSvcBasicHttpEndPoint" contract="ServiceRef.IServiceClient"
                name="XServerSvcBasicHttpEndPoint">
                <identity>
                    <userPrincipalName value="Kevin-EDP\Kevin" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

i try to change the userPrincipalName value to the name of the computer, still my client won't work, when i execute the service, it showed up "the caller was not authenticated by the service"
i am really sure my code is working, when i use basicHttpBinding, and when i look some solution over the internet, most of people suggest to use basicHttpBinding, but that's not the answer i want, i want to use wsHttpBinding for security reason

help me out guys, i am stuck almost 3 days, still can't figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set security mode to none. You can create binding configuration element in the WCF service config file

```
<wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="XServerSvcBasicHttpEndPoint">
<security mode="None"></security>
</binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
```

and use the configuration in the endpoint tag like

```
<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="XServerSvcBasicHttpEndPoint"
                    name="XServerSvcBasicHttpEndPoint" contract="ServerTier.IServiceClient" />
```

Comment: i need the security mode for some security reason, any idea to make it work?

Comment: I think for windows authentication the service and the client must be under same domain. Check if service is also under the domain Kevin-EDP

Comment: so it's not possible with a computer that are not in the same domain? @patel my client won't be in the same domain, cause my wcf will get access over the internet

Comment: yeah i choose this answer because this authentication type need a computer with same "DOMAIN" if not, it won't work.. thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

At the client section change the identity to below format
 identity impersonate="true" userName="domain\user" password="password"/>

Comment: set security mode to None, or Message security mode to None

Comment: i can't set the identity impersonate, it said "the impersonate attribute is not allowed". if i turn the message security to none, it will be a the same as basicHttpBinding right? the message is not encrypted then..

Comment: my config is app.config, not web.config, because i use winform as the wcf host